# Evernote api word search in two notebooks

Tags: evernote

Is it possible to get a word search with all results within two notebooks? Something like (i want all notes containing 'somesearch' in "notebook 1" or "notebook 2"):

```
'somesearch notebook:"notebook 1" or notebook:"notebook 2"'
```

I tried with:

```
'somesearch any: notebook:"notebook 1" notebook:"notebook 2"'
```

But didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote's search grammar doesn't allow multiple notebooks (this is stated in https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/search_grammar.php). It's always either one notebook, or all notebooks (entire account).